# Python type-checking Protocols and Descriptors

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, python-descriptors

I observe a behavior about `typing.Protocol` when Descriptors are involved which I do not quite fully understand. Consider the following code:

```py
import typing as t

T = t.TypeVar('T')


class MyDescriptor(t.Generic[T]):

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __set__(self, instance, value: T):
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner) -> T:
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]


class Named(t.Protocol):

    first_name: str


class Person:

    first_name = MyDescriptor[str]()
    age: int

    def __init__(self):
        self.first_name = 'John'


def greet(obj: Named):
    print(f'Hello {obj.first_name}')


person = Person()
greet(person)
```

Is the class `Person` implicitly implementing the `Named` protocol? [According to mypy, it isn't](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes&gist=ba20cac6a00fcb4f63866e73c868a85b):

```
error: Argument 1 to "greet" has incompatible type "Person"; expected "Named"
note: Following member(s) of "Person" have conflicts:
note:     first_name: expected "str", got "MyDescriptor[str]"
```

I guess that's because mypy quickly concludes that `str` and `MyDescriptor[str]` are simply 2 different types. Fair enough.

However, using a plain `str` for `first_name` or wrapping it in a descriptor that gets and sets a `str` is just an implementation detail. Duck-typing here tells me that the way we will use `first_name` (the interface) won't change.

In other words, `Person` implements `Named`.

As a side note, PyCharm's type-checker does not complain in this particular case (though I am not sure if it's by design or by chance).

According to the intended use of `typing.Protocol`, is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling to find a reference for it, but I think MyPy struggles a little with some of the finer details of descriptors (you can sort of understand why, there's a fair bit of magic going on there). I think a workaround here would just be to use `typing.cast`:

```
import typing as t

T = t.TypeVar('T')


class MyDescriptor(t.Generic[T]):
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __set__(self, instance, value: T) -> None:
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner) -> T:
        name = instance.__dict__[self.name]
        return t.cast(T, name)


class Named(t.Protocol):
    first_name: str


class Person:
    first_name = t.cast(str, MyDescriptor[str]())
    age: int

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.first_name = 'John'


def greet(obj: Named) -> None:
    print(f'Hello {obj.first_name}')


person = Person()
greet(person)
```

This [passes MyPy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes&gist=2887abfc9d436d2d5f07dbd5773f130f).